# Dynamic array seems bigger than the dynamic size variable for it

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, stack, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have class A, in it I have a dynamic array arr and a dynamic variable s which determines the size of the array. At the start of my main I use the constructor for class A which sets s to 2 and fills the arr with dummy objects. Now when I add objects to the array and sort it, objects seem to disappear.
The size of my array (so variable s) gets doubled when there is not enough space in the array, so no free slot available.

The way I display the array is by using a for loop with the limit i < s. So it should display all objects in the array.
Now when I add more objects and the array gets bigger, the previously "lost" objects start to appear again. So it seems like my array is bigger than the variable s, which dynamically determines the size.
How is that possible?

```
class A
private:
   int *s = new int;
   obj *arr = new obj[*s];

//triggers when trying to add an object to the array, but every place from
//arr[0] to arr[s-1] is taken by non dummy object
void A::resize {
    *s *= 2;
     //for loop that fills code with dummy objects
}

void A::display {
     for (int i = 0; i < *s; i++) {
            displayobject(i);
     }
}
```

I had a very similar code last year in university and everything worked fine, can't find my mistake.
I would just use a vector, where i can easily use a for loop to go through the real size, but our prof wants us to use a dynamically alocated array.

Comment: It is undefined behavior to exceed the bounds of the array you allocate. Unfortunately sometimes with UB the program appears to  work even though it is broken.

Comment: `int *s = new int;` you should almost never want to dynamically allocate a single int. This should be `int s;` or better yet `int sizeOfArray;`

Comment: what does this mean ?   

(obj *arr = new obj[*s];)

**s** is a wild pointer

Comment: That to you never set `*s` to a value so you have the additional undefined behavior on allocating an array using a uninitialized / garbage value for the size.

Comment: i tried it with s instead of *s but nothing changes.

Comment: i set *2 to the value of 2 at the start of my main when i create the first obj of class A in the constructor

Comment: You don't have an `A` constructor in the code that is shown. Your functions are missing () also.

Comment: Yeah so my code is really long, I don't really know what I need to add and what not.

Comment: The crazy behavior you see is a result of multiple levels of undefined behavior: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)